# Python shell restarts after printing 4788 lines

Tags: python, recursion, line, limit

So I've been trying to make a recursive-heavy code for completely ethical purposes and I noticed the python shell would restart after about 30 seconds.

At first I thought it was stack overflow from a memory leak so i dealt with it appropriately; still no luck.
I then used tracemalloc to see my memory usage and saw that it was only getting to about 1.3 MB before restarting. I tried a bunch of methods to stop memory leak all giving different final memory sizes but still restaring.

This was when I noticed that, each time, it restarts after printing 4788 lines regardless of the amount of total memory used.

Is there a limit to how many lines python can print or something? Pls help!

```
import random
import sys
import gc
import tracemalloc

tracemalloc.start()

def cleartrash():
    #gc.collect()

##    del genphrase

    print('clearedddddddddddddddddddddddddd')

sys.setrecursionlimit(99999999)
capitalsandlowers = ('qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm')

print ('monkey experiment')
def generatephrase():
    generatedlength = random.randint(5,5)
    genphrase = ( ''.join(random.choice(capitalsandlowers) for i in range(generatedlength)) )
    
    print(genphrase)
    
    if genphrase == 'henry':
        print('done',genphrase)
    else:
        current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
        print(f"Current memory usage is {current / 10**6}MB; Peak was {peak / 10**6}MB")

        #cleartrash()
        del genphrase
        del generatedlength
        #gc.collect()
        generatephrase()

generatephrase()
tracemalloc.stop()
```

Sorry for having to include my entire code but I simply have no clue where or how to go about fixing/ where the problem is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you printing out all the trash? Just do it without printing and count the characters

Comment: And your script did not just finish by finding `henry`? @MichaelHofmann that does not answer the question though.

Comment: I never said I answered his question. That's why I commented. Maybe he hasn't thought about not printing out all the trash...

Comment: True, I apologize.

Comment: FYI, you can use `random.choices(capitalsandlowers, k=generatedlength)` to get a random list of characters.

Comment: How did you "deal with it appropriately"? Using recursion for looping is generally non-Pythonic.

Comment: Does it fail if you replace the recursion with a `while` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a valid use of recursion as the problem itself isn't recursive.  If we change the code to be iterative, it runs in a fixed amount of memory indefinitely:

```
from random import randint, choices
from string import ascii_lowercase as capitalsandlowers

print("Monkey Experiment")

def generatephrase():
    while True:
        generatedlength = randint(5, 5)
        genphrase = ''.join(choices(capitalsandlowers, k=generatedlength))

        print(genphrase)

        if genphrase == 'henry':
            print("Done:", genphrase)
            break

generatephrase()
```

In my test run, it found the target phrase in four minutes:

```
Done: henry
193.963u 28.280s 3:53.61 95.1%  0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

Having tested 9,356,241 random strings.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had WiFi since I've been travelling but I managed to do some playing around on the plane and made the same thing using a while loop instead and it worked perfectly! I'm still not sure how yours worked and my original didn't so I'll have a closer look soon for piece of mind.
Thank you guys for all your help!